# Multiboot single computer

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot

I have 3 hard drives and have installed in different partitions windows xp, windows 7 and windows 10. Ubuntu is alond in a hard drive. How to design a multi boot?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with many way

I  using  Linux GRUB bootloader , you can using live disk boot-repair live cd  for install and fix boot for many os on a pc

Be for that see a good article :
 http://www.zdnet.com/article/seven-ways-to-set-up-multi-booting-with-windows-8-and-linux/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I use VMware Player for these cases. Here is an example of a Zorin installation - Zorin is an Ubuntu derivative.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278957-vmware-player-install-setup-zorin.html#post2295966